# copy file from excel listto other folder

Tags: excel, vba, directory, copy

I am new in VBA, so I have a list of document (**just file name, without extension .pdf, .docx, etc**) in excel column. What I would like to do is to copy all document in the list, from source folder to destination folder.
I already tried some code, it works but the code copy all the files in the folder instead of the file in list (The document list is only in B3:B10).
Any help really appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

```
Sub copyfile()

Dim r As Range
Dim Jajal As Range
Dim sourcePath As String, DestPath As String, FName As String

sourcePath = "C:\Users\"
DestPath = "H:\Users\"

For Each r In Range(Sheet6.Range("B3"), Sheet6.Range("B10")) 'the list document is in the   sheet6 B3:B10
FName = Dir(sourcePath & r)
'Loop while files found
Do While FName <> ""
'Copy the file
FileCopy sourcePath & FName, DestPath & FName
'Search the next file
FName = Dir()
Loop
Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't  need the Dir method

```
For Each r In Range(Sheet6.Range("B3"), Sheet6.Range("B10")) 'the list document is in the   sheet6 B3:B10
    FileCopy sourcePath & r.value, DestPath & r.value
Next
```

Comment: Thank you @freeflow for your answer. Actually, I already tried that code you have suggested before, but it didn't work. It said the file not found.

Comment: Maybe that's because you can't copy a file if you are not providing the full name.  You say your excel list does not contain file extensions so you will need to provide them in the Filecopy statement e.g. r.value & <file extension>